# How do I determine if an expression is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, nonlinear-system

I want to determine if a multi-variable expression is linear.
My current test is to take the second derivative of the expression to see if it is `0`.

Given the expression `x-y = 0`:

`d^2(x-y)/(dxdy) = 0` (linear)

However, if I rearrange to `x/y=1`:

`d^2(x/y)/(dxdy) = -1/y^2` (non-linear)

`x-y = 0` is equivalent to `x/y=1` however, depending on how I have arranged the equation one appears linear and one does not.  Is there a method independent of expression arrangement which determines linearity?

Comment: You only need to check if $f(\vec a+\vec b) = f(\vec a)+f(\vec b)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you explain a little more?

Comment: In your case, $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ where $f(x,y) = x-y$.

Comment: You need to check if $f(a+b,c+d) = f(a,c) + f(b,d)$.

Comment: Why would $x-y=0$ be equivalent to $x/y=0$?

Comment: A null partial crossed second derivative does not test linearity, and your rearrangement should be $x/y=1$ !

Comment: @Yves Daoust that was an error, changed to x/y=1. d^2 is still -1/y^2 I belive.

Comment: @Chris: and your test is still invalid.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Isn't it true that an expression is linear when all second derivatives are 0?

Comment: @Chris: from your counterexample, clearly no, but see my answer.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: So second derivatives provide no useful information when determining linearity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57350/discussion-between-chris-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: No, thanks. Read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is flawed from the beginning, as

$$x-y=0$$ is not an expression but an equation.

You may test the linearity of the expression $$x-y$$ but then the ratio $$\frac xy$$ is just irrelevant.